# Azure function to create new item in SharePoint Online list on schedule

Tags: sharepoint-online, timer-jobs, azure-functions

Very new to Azure Functions.

Need: to create an Azure Function triggered on schedule.  The function would create a new item in a SharePoint Online recording time of the schedule trigger.

What are the option?  No preferences of using C# or PowerShell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can achieve this using Azure Function as well. But I would recommend you to Checkout the Logic App with Sharepoint connector. With Azure Logic Apps and the SharePoint connector, it's easy to create items in SPO and trigger the flow on schedule.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepoint/#create-item

As for the Azure function, you can use CSOM to connect to SharePoint. Since CSOM works fine with .Net framework, I suggest you switch Azure function [runtime](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#languages) to V1.x as it supports .net framework.

You can take a reference of below demo:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/FunctionApp2/FunctionApp2/Function1.cs

More reference:

- [Create List Item in SharePoint using CSOM](https://www.codesharepoint.com/csom/create-list-item-in-sharepoint-using-csom)

BR

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I am interested in trying the Azure Logic App but I don't  believe I could trigger it on schedule.  This is what I really need it to run the code on schedule.  Function looks promising though.